# How do you start a complex polygon

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginner Blender user, and I'm sorry if this isn't the way to ask the question or if I'm even allowed to ask this question.
 I do have a little experience with Inventor, enough so to be able to make the item I am trying to make currently, but not enough to be called a pro.

So here's the shape in question:
[image: I'm trying to get the dark purple part]
I'm trying to get the really dark purple part, I can figure out sizing the pieces, but I don't know how to start the edges from a cube or plane without just making a cube and making all the shapes and boolean difference them out

I get that you are supposed to start with primitive shapes and go from there, but as mentioned earlier I can't figure out how to get a primitive shape to fit the middle.

Comment: maybe take a look at some floral ornament tutorials on youtube, it will help

Comment: If you don't think there is a fitting primitive, then don't start with one. I would simply start adding a few faces along the contours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the poly build tool https://oldetinkererstudio.com/poly-build-tool-blender-2-8-quick-tip/

Answer (score 0):

As your object is kinda flat with no overlaps here is how I would proceed:

I would create a cube merge all its vertices at center (select all the vertices and hit M -> at center) so I get only one vertex. Load a picture of the object I wanted to create as a reference (shift+a -> image -> reference) go to top view (numpad 7) draw the outline of the object (select your vertex and hit ctrl + right click to extrude your vertex where you are pointing with your mouse) fill the shape with quad (select 4 vertices and hit F) extrude the 2D shape, add a subdivision surface and shade it smooth.

Add some geometry where you want some crease and slide the geometry (hit GG to slide vertices along the edges) to get something similar to your reference (see picture 2). If you struggle with subdivision surface modeling you can apply the subdivision surface and jump into sculpting mode to create your desired shape on top of your rough shape. The crease, flatten, grab and smooth brush will be really handy. Finally you can make a bit of retopology if you need something clean with a decent amount of vertices.

Here is a quick sketch of the different steps (from left to right: create the outline / extrude and fill it / add detail and slide vertices / refine your shape in sculpt mode)
[image]

[image]